# Cinder block basement paint - need to cover it for window installers - suggestions

Tags: basement, paint

I am fixing up the basement and would like to cover the deteriorating painted cinderblock under one window of our basement (chipping and paint dust when finger pressed against the wall) due to previous moisture issue). The moisture issue has been taken care of. We have had the paint professionally tested and **it is not lead based paint**

We would like to paint this wall after the window installation after proper prep work (but we need new windows for air circulation first). We want to cover the wall so that there is less of a mess for the installers when they put in the window. It’s not a huge section of wall. **But how do we cover it so that the covering is secure? with plastic and duct tape? duct tape only? another product? other thoughts? Any suggestions or things I need to think about would be welcome.**

Edit to add images:

Window and directly underneath it:[image]

Window showing sill:

[image]

Under window to floor:

[image]

Left of window:

[image]

Right of window:

[image]

Dust I get when finger is drawn across area and side areas

[image]

Comment: Is there a decent area where the paint is still bonded well to the wall?  Any tape will bond to the paint, but if the paint is loose, the whole thing(paint and tape) might just fall down.

Comment: A photo would sure help your cause here...

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I have so far come up with is that it is okay to use duct tape and and plastic (better to use heavier gauge plastic) if as crip69 said there is a way to adhere the plastic to a place where the paint is still bonded well to the wall.

Also, I have noted in the past that some brands of duct tape do not adhere as well as others, so I am going to use a quality brand and test it out ahead of time.